# Ionic 3 <allow-navigation> not working

Tags: ionic3

I´m trying to use a iframe inside my ionic 3 app.

When I run on Android, the iframe works fine, but iOS not.

In my config.xml I add this lines (as described in others stackoverflow questions)

```
<access origin="*" />
<alow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

I add this lines on 2 config.xml files

```
AppName/config.xml

AppName/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml
```

But it still not working. On XCode, I get this error message:

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='gap://ready'
```

The withlist plugin version is

```
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1"
```

Am I forgotten something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your config.xml, please change

- `<alow-navigation href="*" />`

to

- `<allow-navigation href="*" />`